# do American engineering students build projects at the end of their bachelors degree

Tags: thesis, united-states, engineering

In my country Nigeria, Engineering students make projects along with their thesis in order to graduate.... is this the same for Americans ?

Answer (score 2):

This is dependent on a school, however yes, generally undergraduate students complete a capstone (or thesis) that requires them to complete a project demonstrating what they have learned over the program.

Comment: Yep. An implementation that I'm familiar withis Missouri S&T's (AKA Rolla's) requirement that every engineering student do a "experiential learning" requirement. That phrase covers a lot of sins from industry internships though academic research under  the supervision of a professor and on to participation in on of the engineering competition teams, but the whole point is to make the students actually *do* some kind of project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called a Senior Project, or Capstone Project. Usually it runs for 2 consecutive semesters or quarters (typically, but not always). The first term is scoping and project definition, and the second term is the implementation and presentation.

Comment: This varies rather a lot from school to school.

Comment: Agreed. Every school has their own policies. However I believe if the school is ABET accredited, there must be a Senior Project. And I believe ABET even has guidelines what the Senior Project must include. I guess in short, no quality engineering program in the US is a cakewalk.

Comment: @Joe: I had semester-long projects in multiple classes, but no multi-semester capstone, and my program is ABET-accredited.  So whatever guidelines ABET has for design projects, there's not a requirement that all of them be combined in a single project.  Or at least, there wasn't 15 years ago.